# How to treat your saffron right?

Tags: spices, saffron

Similar to [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/how-to-make-saffron-really-color-my-risotto), but not the same (by the way, I like [Hobodave's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/how-to-make-saffron-really-color-my-risotto/4918#4918)).

What's the correct way to treat saffron to get most of the flavor?

I've seen the following methods:

- Let the stems soak in a cup of lukewarm water.
- Warm the stems in oil on a slow flame.
- Wrap the stems in aluminum paper and put it close to a heat source (so it can warm up).
- Fry the stems.
- Soak in white wine for 20' (as per [Peter Taylor's comment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17728/why-do-you-need-to-fry-onions-and-garlic-before-adding-other-ingredients-to-a-dis/17730#17730)).

I'm talking about expensive (stem only) saffron. Should the stems be crushed (before or after soaking)?

The method I usually use is the first one.

Comment: I've heard that grinding/crushing the saffron before soaking drastically reduces the required soaking time with no ill effect on the flavor.  By the way, the "stem only" saffron is really comprised of [stamens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stamen), not stems.

Comment: I've also heard of letting it soak in warm milk ... mainly in Indian dishes.

Comment: I think the biggest reason to not crush it is cosmetic- so you get the little red lines in the finished product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one Italian trick to extract as much as possible from saffron for *risotto alla milanese* is to fill a ladle with hot stock, add the saffron "threads" and then mash them into stock with a spoon. The stock will become a beautiful golden color. Of course stock contains water and fat...

Comment: That's what I've heard, warm, not boiling, stock.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen that some of the flavours/colours in saffron are fat soluble and some water soluble, so soaking in milk should work well. I have also seen recipes that recommend crushing into wine vinegar - I haven't tried this yet but it might be worth testing.

Comment: As Joe commented, that's for Indian dishes, mostly. Very interesting, though.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is that you blend your saffron by a bit of suger and then in glass cup of warm water solve then by a slow flame(indirect) warm it. I use water steam for warming, after 20 min it would be in the best color and taste.

Comment: Never heard of that, but I'll give it a try.